# Colorize Monitoring of Logs

Tags: monitoring, log-files, color, tail, realtime

I sometimes monitor apache and php error logs using `tail` under FreeBSD. Is there any way to get colorized output, either using `tail` or some other command line app?

Alternatively, what is your favorite way to monitor the various web-related logs in realtime?

Answer (score 33):

[Generic Colouriser](https://github.com/garabik/grc) (grc):

[image]

Works with many different file formats.

Example:

```
grc tail -f /var/log/apache/access.log /var/log/apache/error.log
```

[Multitail](https://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/):

[image]

Works with even more file formats :) And is more of a full blown
"tail" with multi windows, diff outputs etc.. Very useful.

Examples:

Merge 2 logfiles in one window:

```
multitail /var/log/apache/access.log -I /var/log/apache/error.log
```

In one window show all new TCP connections and their state changes
using netstat while in the other window displaying the merged access
and error logfiles of apache

```
multitail -R 2 -l "netstat -t" /var/log/apache/access.log -I /var/log/apache/error.log
```

Comment: Could you separate out `grc` and `multitail` into two separate answers so that they can be voted on separately?

Comment: Both `grc` and `multitail` are available in Debian and Ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score 20):

Check out [CCZE](http://freshmeat.net/projects/ccze/), it does the job for me. You have a choice of curses, ansi and html output.

Comment: Where is the download link? It's broken at that site. Screenshot looks good, but, without a link....

Comment: Ok, I found it under Lenny packages, but I am missing some files I guess. I'll get ncurses.

Comment: It's working for me in ubuntu 16.04LTS, just apt-get install ccze. 
To use it, "tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log | ccze" 
It's really useful you can export the output to html too!

Comment: [Host@root:~]# yum install ccze -y

Answer (score 4):

Monitor '/applications' highlighted;

```
tail -f /var/log/system.log | grep /Applications --color
```

Comment: that grep will also filter the results

Answer (score 3):

Check out glTail (http://www.fudgie.org/).  Does way more than you're asking, but maybe that's OK

Answer (score 2):

[Colorize](http://www.flinkmann.de/71-1-Colorizepl.html) is very good tool for simply piping your text through another filter to get fancy ANSI colors. In fact, it's one simple 4kB perl script (almost half of it is just documentation) and it's based on regular expressions.

You can highlight whole line containing given patern (good for hiding unwanted debug logs or highlighting Exceptions) or just highlight pattern in uncolored line (highlighting http response codes).

I have several presets for various file types in separate runnable files. Then I just run `mvn clear install | colorbuild`, `tail -f *.log* | colorlog` or `svn diff | colordif` to have really fancy output.

Comment: available at https://web.archive.org/web/20080321072656/http://www.flinkmann.de/colorize-pl.71.1.html

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try histring, lets you color most of the outputs with simple ANSI codes
http://www.freebsdsoftware.org/misc/histring.html

Comment: abandonware (master site no longer exists)

Answer (score 0):

On FreeBSD use `colorize`.
and add in `.tailrc`:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/tail "$@" | /usr/local/bin/colorize
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [TxtStyle](https://github.com/armandino/TxtStyle), a small utility for colorising logs. You define regular expressions to highlight in `~/.txts.conf` file:

```
[Style="example"]
!red: regex("error")
green: regex("\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d")
# ...
```

And then apply the styles:

```
txts -n example example.log
```

or you can also pipe the output

```
tail -f example.log | txts -n example
```

[image]