# Color awk output on commandline?

Tags: command-line-interface, color, awk

When i process a logfile in awk, is there a possibility to colorize the output on commandline?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the only way is to use ANSI color codes:

```
{ print "Name: \033[1;31m" $2 "\033[0m" }
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Answer (score 3):

For the convenience of future querents, here's a set of functions that one could put into a file called, let's say `color.awk`.

```
function  BLACK(X)             { return "\033[30m"   X "\033[0m" }
function  RED(X)               { return "\033[31m"   X "\033[0m" }
function  GREEN(X)             { return "\033[32m"   X "\033[0m" }
function  YELLOW(X)            { return "\033[33m"   X "\033[0m" }
function  BLUE(X)              { return "\033[34m"   X "\033[0m" }
function  MAGENTA(X)           { return "\033[35m"   X "\033[0m" }
function  CYAN(X)              { return "\033[36m"   X "\033[0m" }
function  WHITE(X)             { return "\033[37m"   X "\033[0m" }
function  BRIGHT_BLACK(X)      { return "\033[90m"   X "\033[0m" }
function  BRIGHT_RED(X)        { return "\033[91m"   X "\033[0m" }
function  BRIGHT_GREEN(X)      { return "\033[92m"   X "\033[0m" }
function  BRIGHT_YELLOW(X)     { return "\033[93m"   X "\033[0m" }
function  BRIGHT_BLUE(X)       { return "\033[94m"   X "\033[0m" }
function  BRIGHT_MAGENTA(X)    { return "\033[95m"   X "\033[0m" }
function  BRIGHT_CYAN(X)       { return "\033[96m"   X "\033[0m" }
function  BRIGHT_WHITE(X)      { return "\033[97m"   X "\033[0m" }
function  BG_BLACK(X)          { return "\033[40m"   X "\033[0m" }
function  BG_RED(X)            { return "\033[41m"   X "\033[0m" }
function  BG_GREEN(X)          { return "\033[42m"   X "\033[0m" }
function  BG_YELLOW(X)         { return "\033[43m"   X "\033[0m" }
function  BG_BLUE(X)           { return "\033[44m"   X "\033[0m" }
function  BG_MAGENTA(X)        { return "\033[45m"   X "\033[0m" }
function  BG_CYAN(X)           { return "\033[46m"   X "\033[0m" }
function  BG_WHITE(X)          { return "\033[47m"   X "\033[0m" }
function  BG_BRIGHT_BLACK(X)   { return "\033[100m"  X "\033[0m" }
function  BG_BRIGHT_RED(X)     { return "\033[101m"  X "\033[0m" }
function  BG_BRIGHT_GREEN(X)   { return "\033[102m"  X "\033[0m" }
function  BG_BRIGHT_YELLOW(X)  { return "\033[103m"  X "\033[0m" }
function  BG_BRIGHT_BLUE(X)    { return "\033[104m"  X "\033[0m" }
function  BG_BRIGHT_MAGENTA(X) { return "\033[105m"  X "\033[0m" }
function  BG_BRIGHT_CYAN(X)    { return "\033[106m"  X "\033[0m" }
function  BG_BRIGHT_WHITE(X)   { return "\033[107m"  X "\033[0m" }
function  SKYBLUE(X)           { return "\033[38;2;40;177;249m" X "\033[0m" }
```

One could then use these things to color a column like so.

```
awk -f color.awk -e '{$1 = RED($1); print}' input.log
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several programs that can colorize logfiles, source code and general text. In addition to the ones mentioned in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/53894/colorize-monitoring-of-logs), there are:

- [SuperCat](http://supercat.nosredna.net/index.html)
- [Highlight](http://www.andre-simon.de/)
- [Pygmentize](http://pygments.org/docs/cmdline/)